# How can I compare with string constants in angular's directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It works:

```
<player-card
    flex ...
    is-player-messi-or-under="ctrl.playerName === 'Messi' || ctrl.playerName === undefined">
</player-card>
```

I've got a constant `Name.MESSI = 'Messi'` outside of this file but if I type

```
<player-card
    flex ...
    is-player-messi-or-under="ctrl.playerName === Name.MESSI || ctrl.playerName === undefined">
</player-card>
```

it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `Name.MESSI` defined? Is it in the scope?

Comment: @f-CJ nope, outside.

Comment: Well, it's been some time since I did angularjs, but if it is not in the scope how angularjs is going to resolve the value of `Name.MESSI`.

Comment: Actually it's, I checked it.

Comment: You must have the Name constant assigned to a variable in your controller. You can do something like: `this.Name = Name` and it shall work.